# Sorting in Pgfplotstable not working

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, sorting

I am trying to sort a table I created with the pgfplotstable package and I can't find out why it is not working.

```
\pgfplotstableset{col sep=semicolon, use comma, fixed, set thousands separator={}}
\pgfplotstableread
{
Matrikelnummer;Note     
1010123;1.4
1010121;2.3
1010122;1.1
}\loadedtable

\pgfplotstabletypeset[sort, sort key={Matrikelnummer}]\loadedtable
```

When I change the sort key to "Note" it works like a charm. But the example above simply does not change the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `sort cmp={int <}` it works fine.

[image: sorted table]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableset{col sep=semicolon, use comma, fixed, set thousands separator={}}
\pgfplotstableread
{
Matrikelnummer;Note     
1010123;1.4
1010121;2.3
1010122;1.1
}\loadedtable

\pgfplotstabletypeset[sort,sort cmp={int <},sort key=Matrikelnummer]\loadedtable

\end{document}
```

Comment: What does this addition do? I assume int is the short term for integer. Does this compare parameter defines that it is an integer?

Comment: @baghira Yes, `int` is for integer. It tells `pgfplotstable` what kind of comparison function to use for the sorting, and `int <` expects integer values as inputs. The default is `float <`, which expects floats as inputs, and that didn't seem to work for your integers.

Comment: Tank you for the answer! :-)