# pgfplotstable with bold an repeated headlines and sorting

Tags: pgfplotstable, bold

My problem is similar to that of: 
[Sorting in Pgfplotstable not working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414271/sorting-in-pgfplotstable-not-working)
but it is not quite answered there. This user wants to sort a table 
{
Matrikelnummer;Note
1010123;1.4 
1010121;2.3 
1010122;1.1 
}\loadedtable 
I have a similar but longer table with 7 cols. and over several pages.

I would like to have the headline 
Matrikelnummer;Note 
in bold and repeated (in bold) on every page. 
But if I change the headline to 
\textbf{Matrikelnummer};\textbf{Note}
the sorting does not work any more and it throws an error. 
Here is my min. example:
%--------------------------- 
\pgfplotstableset{ 
begin table=\begin{longtable}, 
end table=\end{longtable}, 
every head row/.append style={after row={% 
\endfirsthead 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \  
\endhead  
}, 
}, 
col sep=semicolon, string type}  
\pgfplotstableread  
{ 
*... here comes my long data section, cols separated by semicolon*  
}\loadedtable 
% Sorting:  
\pgfplotstabletypeset[sort,sort cmp={string <},sort key=Matrikelnummer]\loadedtable 
%--------------------------- 
Without bold and repeated headlines sorting works fine. 
Where do I enter that the headlines get repeated and appear bold, and how do I sort? 
Thanks in advance for any idea!

Comment: please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code how to properly format your code block.

Comment: ?? I did. What is wrong with my code block?

Comment: Your code block is just normal text with tons of html special markup. This means that the scroll bars are missing which adds a lot of line breaks and people who use extensions for a copy to clipboard button, won't be able to easily copy your code.

Comment: Please either indent your code by four spaces or place it in code fences